# Usar transition para mover objetos posicionados absolutamente

Tags: css, animación, position, transition

Tengo un cuadro posicionado relativamente que funciona como contenedor para otros 4 cuadrados más pequeños posicionados absolutamente. Quiero que al hacer `:hover` sobre el contenedor, todos los cuadros se muevan en el sentido del reloj, pero de forma suave. Intenté hacerlo usando las propiedades de `position` (`top`, `right`, `bottom` y `left`), sin embargo. el movimiento de los cuadros no se anima, tal como se muestra a continuación:

```css
.container{
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    margin: 20px auto;
    background: #ddd;
    position: relative;
    transition: all 1s;
}

.container__box-1{
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    background: #f00;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}

.container__box-2{
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    background: #0f0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
}

.container__box-3{
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    background: #0ff;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}

.container__box-4{
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    background: #00f;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}

.container:hover > .container__box-1{
    right: 0;
    transition: all 1s;
}

.container:hover > .container__box-2{
    bottom: 0;
    transition: all 1s;
}

.container:hover > .container__box-3{
    top: 0;
    transition: all 1s;
}

.container:hover > .container__box-4{
    left: 0;
    transition: all 1s;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="container__box-1"></div>
    <div class="container__box-2"></div>
    <div class="container__box-3"></div>
    <div class="container__box-4"></div>
</div>
```

`transition` no me está funcionando en ese caso. Sin embargo, usando la propiedad `margin` sí me funciona:

```css
.container{
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    margin: 20px auto;
    background: #ddd;
    position: relative;
    transition: all 1s;
}

.container__box-1{
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    background: #f00;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}

.container__box-2{
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    background: #0f0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
}

.container__box-3{
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    background: #0ff;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}

.container__box-4{
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    background: #00f;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}

.container:hover > .container__box-1{
    margin-left: calc(300px - 50px);
    transition: all 1s;
}

.container:hover > .container__box-2{
    margin-top: calc(300px - 50px);
    transition: all 1s;
}

.container:hover > .container__box-3{
    margin-bottom: calc(300px - 50px);
    transition: all 1s;
}

.container:hover > .container__box-4{
    margin-right: calc(300px - 50px);
    transition: all 1s;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="container__box-1"></div>
    <div class="container__box-2"></div>
    <div class="container__box-3"></div>
    <div class="container__box-4"></div>
</div>
```

Pero yo quiero mover las cajas de forma animada sin usar márgenes, o sea mediante el posicionamiento. ¿Existe alguna forma de hacer esto sin Javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para que te funcione con `top`,`bottom`,`left` y `right`, para empezar solo necesitas poner un `transition: all 0.4s;` en los div's que quieras mover, y una vez posicionados (con `top`,`bottom`,`left` y `right`) en el hover tenemos que cambiar la misma propiedad, te dejo como lo he echo yo, espero que te sirva.

```css
.container{
    position: relative;
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    margin: 20px auto;
    background: #ddd;
    display: flex;
}

.container div{
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    transition: all 0.4s;
}

.container__box-1{
    background: #f00;
    left: 0;
}

.container__box-2{
    background: #0f0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
}

.container__box-3{
    background: #0ff;
    bottom: 0;
}

.container__box-4{
    background: #00f;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}


/* hover */
.container:hover > .container__box-1{
    left: calc(100% - 50px);
}

.container:hover > .container__box-2{
    top: calc(100% - 50px);
}

.container:hover > .container__box-3{
    bottom: calc(100% - 50px);
}

.container:hover > .container__box-4{
    right: calc(100% - 50px);
}
```

```html
 <div class="container">
        <div class="container__box-1"></div>
        <div class="container__box-2"></div>
        <div class="container__box-3"></div>
        <div class="container__box-4"></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias @Thecots